# how to send variable to php from objective c

Tags: php, objective-c, post

I'm looking for a simple code to write a string in objective c using textfiel and send it to php.

for example this, so in the internet page i see al title:

in PHP

```
<?php 
$title = $_POST['title'];
 echo "Title: ". $title;
?>
```

and objective c

> NSString *eventTitle=@"test";
>
> NSString *myRequestString = [NSString
>   stringWithFormat:@"title=%@",eventTitle];
>
> NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString
>   UTF8String] length:       [myRequestString length]];
>   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
>   initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:
>   @"http://www.myDomain.com/phpfilename.php"]];
>
> [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
>
> [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>   forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
>
> [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
>
> NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request
>   returningResponse: nil error: nil];
>
> NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData
>   bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>   NSLog(@"%@",response);

sorry if they are simple and novice with php

thanks for all

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: dont reinvent the wheel-> AFNetworking on github!!!

Comment: hei woz..in the internaet page i can't see the test. i see also title:                ,but i want to see title:test

Comment: To see the page with the value on it, you have to save the value to a database in PHP. Have a separate page to query the database and display the value.

Comment: so can i send "test" to php and after read test from another application?

Comment: You need to understand how to receive data from the POST request. The Objective-C aspect looks correct. Catch the POST request from the device, save it to a database, read the database using a query launched by your PHP code and display it.

Comment: I was thinking of not using a database

ok thank you very much